# Is it possible to pass '$(this)' on to a delegated user function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function myfunc() {
  alert($(this));
}

$("#SELECTOR").delegate("SELECTOR","click",myfunc);
```

This is about clicking on different images, therefore, I'd really love to use the $(this) variable in my user function.

Is that possible? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried it? That should work.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: I did try it, and it does not work for some reason.

Comment: I'd expect to get the image back, since that's what I'm clicking on.

Comment: Try this jsfiddle - is this not what you're talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/8euum/

Comment: Actually, that's what I meant http://jsfiddle.net/8euum/1/
But here it actually works....

Comment: Ya, those two are fundamentally the same in terms of how `this` gets bound.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but still, it does not work on my site.. :S

Comment: Found it: http://jsfiddle.net/8euum/2/
.attr('id') works, but .id does not

Comment: Correct, `.attr('id')` is for jQuery objects, `.id` is for DOM elements. If you want to use .id, you'd have to `$(this)[0].id`

Comment: @MrSlayer no point wrapping `this` in jquery just to unwrap it  to arrive at `this.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The syntax for delegate is:

```
$('#container').delegate('selector','event',function(){
//code to respond to event
});//end delegate
```

which is pretty much what you already have,..

A working example which includes the method you are attempting is here - http://jsfiddle.net/E9dgU/5/